# Adding navigation controller to custom designed table view which have calender view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

want my table to show up only half way from the bottom of the screen, the upper half meant for the calendar view. To do this, I added a table view through code using CGRectMake specifying the (x,y) co-ordinates I wanted it to start at.

Now, I want each row of this table to navigate to a new view. How do I make the navigation controller push my new view? I added a navigation controller to my main view

```
TaskDetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[TaskDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TaskDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController  animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to apply navigation from a view controller, that view controller should be a part of the navigation viewcontroller stack.

So what you have to do is instead of adding the rootViewController directly, You create a navigation controller, and set the rootViewcontroller to it(as rootViewController property). Once you set it, You can add navigation controller in place of rootViewController added previously.

Then on click you can use. 
[self.navigationController push..... animated:..];

*You can check it. If try to access the navigationController by self.navigationController currently it would be returning nil.*

Comment: kk.. thanks... it worked iset the navigation property to the root view controller..

Comment: I guess you can accept the answer if it worked, by clicking the tick mark below the vote up, there is nothing special in this answer to vote up :-)